# Wordpress Action Upon Edit Post Load

Tags: php, wordpress

I am running a function whenever a Post is Updated by using `add_action('save_post', 'transcription');`

I am trying to have the function also run whenever the Edit Post is loaded (before it is Updated or Saved), however when I add:

```
add_action('post.php', 'transcription');
```

Nothing Happens.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Come to find out that when you do an add-action on load-post.php (the correct action for when you want to edit the individual post), it does not pass the post_id.  Since my transcription module was dependent on getting the post ID, it was as simple as run $_GET['post'] and assigning it to the post_id variable transcription required

```
add_action( 'load-post.php', 'transcription' );
function transcription($post_id)  {
//Transcription Status 0 = Not Transcribed but uploaded, 1=Submitted for Transcription, 2=Transcribed 3=Transcribed and Addd to Post
    $post_id = $_GET[ 'post' ];
//Do whatever with transcription
}
```

This turns out to be the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
add_action( 'load-edit.php', 'post_listing_page' );
function post_listing_page() {
    //this is the wp-admin edit.php post listing page!
}
```

in your case:

```
add_action( 'load-edit.php', 'transcription' );
```

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/load-(page)

Comment: So this is not loading on load-edit when I hit the post.  Does it mater that it is a custom post type?  I set up an error log to trigger whenever it hits, but it only hits when you go back to the main post type listing (where it lists all articles under that post type).  I can't seem to get it to trigger on load of the edit post page still.